# OneAuth Multiple Logins

Tags: laravel

I am a newbie to laravel and trying to handle multiple social login into my website.

So far i have tried following,
Installed OneAuth and was able to get all past the authentication until it goes to my register part of controller. When i look up into DB in the client table i get user_id field set to 0. So what i assume from my understanding is that this is a foreign key that links same user to multiple Providers. Yes thats what made me excited.

So here is where i get stuck. Lets say after facebook login i render register view where email_id is populated that was returned from facebook. User fills in all the required fields and the Users table is populated. Now how do i update the OneAuth client table user_id field with the id in the user table that was just created.

I would like to know if what i am doing is correct? If yes how do i tackle the given problem.

Update:

We can sync table by using this event.

```
Event::fire('oneauth.sync', array( $user->id )  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user = new User;
if ($_POST)
{
    // it a POST Request, you should validate the form
    $user->nickname = Input::get('username');
    $user->password = Hash::create(Input::get('password'));
    $user->email    = Input::get('email');
} else {
  $user_data = Session::get('oneauth'); 
  $existing_user = User::where_uid($user_data['info']['uid'])->first();
  if (is_object($existing_user)){
    $user = $existing_user;
    $user->setUserData($user_data);
  } else {
    $user->setUserData($user_data);
  }
}
$user->save();

Auth::login($user->id, true);

Event::fire('oneauth.sync', array($user->id));
```